# ComboBox DataBinding does not show value, why?

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I have a class with the following structure:

```
public class Grupo
{
    public virtual int IdGrupo { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    public virtual int IdUsuario { get; private set; }
    public virtual Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }
    public virtual string Senha { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Administrador { get; set; }
}
```

I have a class that implement some methods to populate a BindingList:

```
BindingList<Usuario> Usuariolst = UsuarioRepository.GetAll();
BindingList<Grupo> Grupolst = GrupoRepository.GetAll();
```

In my Form1, I have a ComboBox named ComboBox1 and a BindingSource named = BindingSource1, after populate the bindinglists I can set ComboBox with the list:

```
BindingSource1.DataSource = Usuariolst;
ComboBox1.DataSource = Grupolst;
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.BindingSource1, "Grupo", true));
```

All CRUD works nice, the problem is when I load Usuariolst and set current position of BindingSource1, the combobox don't display the correct value associated, but when I save the correct value is set, I'm using nhibernate to do this.

The combobox databind seems to be linked properly, so the correct value is not shown.

Comment: I have exactly thesame problem. No solutions for me yet. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Specify the update mode to `OnPropertyChanged`:

```
ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", 
    this.BindingSource1, "Grupo", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

**Edit:** Try to replace `this.BindigSource1` by `Usuariolst`:

```
ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", 
    Usuariolst, "Grupo", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Comment: I tried like you told me, but... didn't work... I'm scared, what's wrong with my combobox?

Answer (score 0):

To determine what could be going on: put a breakpoint in the `Grupo` property setter; then watch for the setter being called when the `DataSource` is being set such that the `Grupo` value is being changed from what was loaded from the repository (probably to null).

If this is the case, try setting the combo box DataSource after adding the binding.

Comment: In bindingsource1 CurrentChanged event if I get BindingSource1.Current, the Grupo property is correctly setted, but the combobox does not match... I dont know what's happen...

Comment: I tried to do your suggestion, but the Grupo property is the correct value, if I put a breakpoint in event BindingSource1_CurrentChanged, the value from bindingsource1.Current is correct too, but the combobox dont show the value.... thanks.... any suggestion?

Comment: I'm afraid that was my stab in the dark. Shame it didn't work. I have had a harder than usual time with ComboBox SelectedValue and SelectedItem bindings in the past - mostly around managing SelectedIndex after changing or updating datasources.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, I found the only solution was to ignore databindings and implement the same functionality manually, using the `Combobox.SelectionChangeCommitted` event to register changes to the combobox, and `Combobox.SelectedItem` to set the item initially.

I used something like

```
comboBox.SelectedItem = comboBox.Items
                                .Cast<Usuario>()
                                .FirstOrDefault(u => u.IdGrupo.Equals(usuario.Grupo.IdGrupo));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
BindingSource1.DataSource = Usuariolst;
ComboBox1.DataSource = Grupolst;
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
// This will do the trick
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "IdGrupo";
```

Comment: If you want to show the ComboBox the current value from the datasource, you need to set property ValueMember